# GORM panics when `gorm.Model` not embedded

Tags: go, go-gorm

This is my model. Note that I don't want to embed `gorm.Model` into my structs.

```
type Order struct {
    OrderID   uint64     `gorm:"column:order_id" gorm:"primaryKey" gorm:"unique"`
    Cart      Cart       `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    CreatedBy UserID     `gorm:"index"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:nano"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:nano"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time
}

type Category struct {
    ID        uint64     `gorm:"column:category_id" gorm:"primaryKey" gorm:"unique"`
    Name      string     `gorm:"index"`
    Image     string     
    Products  []Product  `gorm:"foreignKey:product_id" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    CreatedBy UserID     `gorm:"index" gorm:"type:bytea"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:nano"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:nano"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time 
}

type Cart struct {
    UserID    UserID     `gorm:"column:user_id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Products  []Product  `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    Price     float64   
    CreatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:nano"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:nano"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time 
}

type Product struct {
    ID        uint64     `gorm:"column:product_id" gorm:"primaryKey" gorm:"unique"`
    Name      string     `gorm:"index"`
    Price     float64    `gorm:"index"`
    Rating    uint       `gorm:"index"`
    Image     string     
    CreatedBy UserID     `gorm:"index" gorm:"type:bytea"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:nano"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:nano"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time 
}
```

When I use AutoMigrate, I get the following errors:

```
[error] invalid field found for struct moonspace/model.Cart's field Products: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

I have tried changing the `foreignKey:UserID` to `foreignKey:user_id` but the error remains the same.

Here is my auto-migrate:

```
func createPostgresCLI(cfg types.Config, config ...any) *gorm.DB {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(cfg.Url))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&model.Order{}, &model.Cart{}, &model.Category{}, &model.Product{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Error creating database: %w", err))
    }

    return db
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, when I use `gorm.Model`, and when I try to insert a `Product` into a `Category`, I'm getting a foreign key constraint error. I'm trying to add it through associations.

Answer (score 1):

**Category <==> Product**: foreign key column needs to be included in Product which will reference Category ID. CUrrent config when working will update product ID with category ID, which will be wrong

```
type Category struct {
    ID       uint64 `gorm:"column:category_id;primaryKey"`
    Products  []Product  `gorm:"foreignKey:CategoryID" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    ....
}

type Product struct {
    ID        uint64     `gorm:"column:product_id" gorm:"primaryKey" gorm:"unique"`
    CategoryID uint64 // New field to hold category ID.
    ....
}
```

**Cart <===> Product** relation can be modelled as [many2many](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Many-To-Many) with a join table to store products' and carts' IDs, might not need foreign key here.

```
type Cart struct {
    CartID   uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Products []Product `gorm:"many2many:cart_products"`
    ....
}
```

**Also** You can use combine all gorm tags into one, no need for repeating.

Comment: Thank you very much. If this starts working I'll mark this as an accepted answer.